# Genitive and accusative case of animate words

Tags: грамматика

I know that in Russian we use genitive case for the accusative case of animate masculine and feminine words.

My question is: when I’m doing grammatical analysis of the words, what do I have to write for them? Do I have to write that they are in accusative case, even if I know it’s formed like it is genitive? Or do I have to simply write that it is genitive case?

Comment: Words of declension I (those ending in *-a / -я*, masculine and feminine alike) have a distinct accusative form in singular: *мама (nom.) / нет мамы (gen.) / любить маму (acc.)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, we don't use genitive (or nominative for inanimated nouns) for the accusative. They just look alike. So you must write accusative.